# Split a string with a condition in python

Tags: python, split

Below is Code

```
xyz = "2022/08/17 15:10:04.716, I, width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98)"
print(xyz.split(','))
```

**Input:** "2022/08/17 15:10:04.716, I, width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98)"

**Output:** ['2022/08/17 15:10:04.716', ' I', **' width = 67 height = 52 position = (389'**, **'98)'**]

**I don't want to split comma in "position = (389,98)".**

**Output required:** ['2022/08/17 15:10:04.716', ' I', ' width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98)']

How can I achieve this??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will always be 3 or more commas,

```
xyz.split(',', maxsplit=2)
```

Output

```
['2022/08/17 15:10:04.716', ' I', ' width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98)']
```

If the input is

```
abc = "width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98), 2022/08/17 15:10:04.716, I"
```

You can choose to perform the split starting from the right end

```
abc.rsplit(',', maxsplit=2)
```

Output:

```
['width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98)', ' 2022/08/17 15:10:04.716', ' I']
```

Comment: Thanks, What if input is like "width = 67 height = 52 position = (389,98), 2022/08/17 15:10:04.716, I" ???